# Nginx: when to use proxy_set_header Host $host vs $proxy_host

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've been reading up on reverse proxying and am wondering when `proxy_set_header Host $host` is appropriate over `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host`. I did some research and in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching) it says that in most cases we set Host to $host. Then why does nginx default to $proxy_host? To help me understand more concretely, will the reverse proxy configuration [here](https://whatididtodowhatidid.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/subdomains-for-ports-on-same-ubuntu-server-with-nginx-reverse-proxy/) (bottom of article) still work if we use $proxy_host instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 52):

In general there is no need to explicitly do `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host` because it's the default. If you need to call a server by something *other* than what is in the `proxy_pass` directive, then you will need to override via `proxy_set_header something`.

If you want to proxy the *same* host as was in your `server_name` directive, then you would have occasion to use `proxy_set_header $host`. This would commonly be the case if perhaps the actual application is hosted on another port or on some internal server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.example.com;
    
    location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

If the name you are calling the upstream is not its actual DNS name, then you might have something like:

```
# 192.168.2.1 responds to site.example.com, but
# site.example.com doesn't actually resolve to 192.168.2.1
proxy_pass http://192.168.2.1;
proxy_set_header Host site.example.com;
```

Another case might be for "name-based" virtual hosting where there is a useful DNS name for the upstream, but you would like to call it by another name.

```
proxy_pass http://origin.example.com;
proxy_set_header Host site.example.com
```

Comment: Does the order of `proxy_pass` and `proxy_set_header` matter?

Comment: @iBug Nope! the `upstream` module will read each of the settings applicable for its internal phases, and then apply the when it issues the actual `proxy_pass`. You'll get the exact same behavior if the `proxy_set_header` is *after* `proxy_pass` in the config.

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding the wording of the definitions of `$host`and `$proxy_host`. So is this wrong: A client sends a request to an nginx server **A** which proxy passes it to backend **B**. Then `$host` would be the url of **A**, while `$proxy_host` would be the url of **B**. So if I want *future* requests of the client to still be directed at **A**, I would want to use `$host`? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

`$proxy_host` is a tag about upstreams servers, so nginx do this one by default.

If you want to add other tag(header) about the host, use `$host`.