# How to proxy pass a request for a directory listing to another server (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, webserver, static-files, proxypass

I am just posting this here as an answer to a question I had for a fairly nuanced problem.

I have two servers (two different machines):

```
backend.website.com
www.website.com
```

Some static files are hosted in a directory called `/audiofiles`, these need to be accessible at `www.website.com/audiofiles`, but are stored on the machine for `backend.website.com`. Yes, this is a convoluted requirement, but it is the case in our situation and cannot be changed.

My answer below is how *we* accomplished this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the config that let us accomplish this:

**backend.website.com:**

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name backend.website.com;
  root /var/www/backend/;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location ^~ /audiofiles/ {
    alias /some/other/folder/audiofiles/;
    autoindex on;
    break;
  }

  # ... other stuff
}
```

**[www.website.com](http://www.website.com)**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name website.com www.website.com;

  location /audiofiles/ {
    proxy_pass         https://backend.website.com;
    proxy_redirect     /audiofiles/ https://www.website.com/audiofiles/;
    proxy_set_header   Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
  
  # ... other stuff
}
```